# Is there a way to use pluralize() inside a model rather than a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pluralize

It seems `pluralize` only works within a view -- is there some way that my models can use `pluralize` too?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Rather than extend things, I just it like this:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.pluralize(count, 'mystring')
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Very helpful. This sort of case often pops up just once in a model or controller. Why add a new line when it can be done in one go!

Comment: I'd recommend doing this unless you really need view helpers all over your model (which you probably shouldn't). If you just include `ActionController::Base.helpers` at the top, it's less obvious where `pluralize` is being pulled in from and cause confusion in the future. You're also included all the other helpers by doing that. I doubt there's a performance loss there, but certainly a code smell.

Answer (score 59):

Add this to your model:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
```

Comment: quick way if I want to add it in all the models?

Comment: @coorasse Add it as a base model that all your models inherit from.

Comment: Instead of polluting your model with lot of unwanted methods, just see @Tom Rossi's answer below. Much better.

Answer (score 17):

My favorite way is to create a TextHelper in my app that provides these as class methods for use in my model:

**app/helpers/text_helper.rb**

```
module TextHelper                       
  extend ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
end
```

**app/models/any_model.rb**

```
def validate_something
  ...
  errors.add(:base, "#{TextHelper.pluralize(count, 'things')} are missing")
end
```

Including ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper in your models works, but you also litter up your model with lots of helper methods that don't need to be there.

It's also not nearly as clear where the pluralize method came from in your model. This method makes it explicit - `TextHelper.pluralize`.

Finally, you won't have to add an include to every model that wants to pluralize something; you can just call it on TextHelper directly.

Answer (score 4):

YOu can add a method like this in your model

```
  def self.pluralize(word)
    ActiveSupport::Inflector.pluralize(word)
  end
```

and call it in this way

```
City.pluralize("ruby")
=> "rubies"
```

Comment: What you suggested is already built into String, like "ruby".pluralize. I think the question was regarding ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper's pluralize(number, word) method.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed :)

Comment: This is not the same pluralize helper that it used in the view. See @Sam Ruby's answer

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in rails 5.1 (see 2nd method, first method is calling it.)

```
# gets a count of the users certifications, if they have any.
def certifications_count
  @certifications_count = self.certifications.count
  unless @certifications_count == 0 
    return pluralize_it(@certifications_count, "certification")
  end
end

# custom helper method to pluralize.
def pluralize_it(count, string)
  return ActionController::Base.helpers.pluralize(count, string)
end
```