# undefined method `pluralizer' in _form.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails so maybe I'm missing something here but I am getting the following error when trying to use pluralizer in my form.

```
   undefined method `pluralizer' for #<#<Class:0x00000002f76528>:0x000000054a5ec0>
```

Here is the section in the form

```
  <h2><%= pluralizer(normal_hour.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this normal_hour from being saved:</h2>
  <ul>
  <% normal_hour.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
```

Do I need to do a include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper somewhere?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806473/rails-3-is-there-a-way-to-use-pluralize-inside-a-model-seems-to-only-work-in

Comment: For additional info please view the full project at https://github.com/wvulibraries/LibManagementTool/tree/granularpermissions

Comment: Plus I dont think the method is `pluralizer`, it is `pluralize`

Comment: thanks that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is `pluralize` and not `pluralizer`.
Read more about it [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/pluralize)

Also, you do not need to include `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper` unless you would like to use `pluralize` in a model. [Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806473/rails-3-is-there-a-way-to-use-pluralize-inside-a-model-seems-to-only-work-in)